# How to escape sharp(#) symbol in path?

Tags: c#, .net, escaping

I'm trying to get absolute path from string. Everything worked fine before i met path that contains sparp(#) symbol.
Here is my example:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var codeBase = "file:///C:/#MyFolder/TestApp/bin/Debug/net6.0-windows/TestApp.dll";
            var uri = new Uri(codeBase);
            var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.AbsolutePath);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
    }
```

And `Uri.AbsolutePath` returns `C:\`. Yeah `Uri.AbsolutePath` doesn't work with `#` symbol. But what sould i do in this case to get absolute path?
Honestly it's the first time i see that someone use this symbol in folder name.

Comment: Have you tried to use `%23` instead of `#`?

Comment: @PeterCsala `%23` works fine. Does it mean that i need to replace `#` first?

Comment: yepp, that's correct.

Comment: Technically, that's the number or hash symbol, the sharp symbol is backwards `♯`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Uri you can use the `%23` to escape the [reserved `#` symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding#Reserved_characters):

```
var codeBase = "file:///C:/%23MyFolder/TestApp/bin/Debug/net6.0-windows/TestApp.dll";
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ65IJwAoBEgPBuAg+/gJQDc6AbgIZgAEAxgPYAmApgEK0DOHDALwN8AMwCWAGw4gA9PIDCcgKQIAzAFkAngDEWkzmFkAVDr2ABBAA5XZAI3FRZAEQ52IAc1lQOwAGwAdAAMALQA7o5sLGG8JmaWNgFskpL4VGh0jBBg4kIMPmEMAKo5uKycPPyUNPQMVrTAABZ5JeIBRT68TLRWHM4NtADKwDlQHrjZbRZ2vPoQwBwACg2N1WhYePVNlEA=)

Comment: So i need to replace symbol first? I just thought that there is some standart method to escape  whole string.  But i'm fine with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try some thing like this:

```
var codeBase = "file:///C:/#MyFolder/TestApp/bin/Debug/net6.0-windows/TestApp.dll";
    var uri = new Uri(codeBase);
    var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.AbsolutePath);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
```

The Uri will work for you

Comment: How is this different to the op code?

Answer (score -1):

#FolderName is the replacement for the project folder on your PC.

To get the exact URL locate the file and click here:[image: Example Image]

clicking there will convert it into a URL:
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).